# Does Deleting a Dynamically Allocated Vector Clear It's Contents

Tags: c++, vector, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

Say I have:

```
vector<string>* foo = new vector<string>();
```

I add a ton of stuff to it, use it, and then I just call:

```
delete foo;
```

Did I need to call `foo.clear();` first? Or will the `delete` call the destructor.

Please no comments regarding the folly of this, I know that at a minimum auto-pointers should be used here. This behavior is in the code base I'm working in and it's outside scope for me to go fix it.

Comment: [This is quite easy to test, with a `vector<T>` where `T` writes to `std::cout` on destruction](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a63601aa8f9d5f6).

Comment: You can find information on the standard containers and pretty much everything else from the standard at multiple places on the internet.
You could've searched for "std::vector destructor" to find that information

Comment: Once you have deleted it why do you care if it has been cleared?

Comment: @KABoissonneault but now that information is also here, which is good. Do you know of a duplicate?

Comment: @Ben I couldn't find a duplicate but I have been known to miss them.

Comment: @Ben He could be concerned about the contained objects' destructors being called.

Comment: @Ben: So that you don't get memory leaks? Or other bad effects of failed element destruction? Why _wouldn't_ you care?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You should add that link to your answer. It's an excellent proof.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, the `vector`'s destructor will be called, and this will clear its contents.**

`delete` calls the destructor before de-allocating memory, and vector's destructor implicitly calls `.clear()` (as you know from letting an automatic-storage duration `vector` fall out of scope).

This is quite easy to test, with a `vector<T>` where `T` writes to `std::cout` on destruction (though watch out for copies inside of the `vector`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    T() { std::cout << "!\n"; }
    T(const T&) { std::cout << "*\n"; }
    ~T() { std::cout << "~\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<T>* ptr = new std::vector<T>();
    ptr->emplace_back();
    ptr->emplace_back();
    ptr->emplace_back();

    delete(ptr);  // expecting as many "~" as "!" and "*" combined
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a63601aa8f9d5f6))

Answer (score 3):

According to the requirements of containers (the C++ Standard, Table 96 — Container requirements)

(&a)->~X() - **the destructor is applied to every element of a**; all the memory is deallocated.

where X denotes a container class containing objects of type T, a and b denote values of type X,